# using regular expressions to ignore a substring

Tags: java, regex

I am using java and have a pattern like `I am going to manchester`
I want to use regular expression to match this will all sentences that are of the type `I am going` (some string) `to manchester`. 
So my string `i am going to manchester` will also match `I am going with my family to manchester`

Does anyone know the regex to achieve this?

I tried the following but it won't work:

```
Pattern.compile("i am going (\\w+) to mancheter")
```

I am using `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

Comment: `I am going( .+)? to manchester` or simply `I am going\b.* to manchester`?

Comment: [`i am going.+?manchester\.`](https://regex101.com/r/Ej9A5j/1) but generally I think this is not advisable.

Comment: Does the string "I am going to manchester" also have to be rejected?

Comment: No the aim is to match any string of the form "I am going (some sub string) to manchester"

Comment: Thank you @ctwheels \b.* works could you explain that please .

Comment: @MosesS `\b` asserts the position as a word boundary (to ensure `going` doesn't have anything following it, i.e. `goings` or something). The `.*` matches any character any number of times.

Answer (score 0):

**Try it:**

Input:

```
I am going with my family to manchester potato
```

Output:

```
I am going with my family to manchester
```

**Java Code:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld {
 // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  final String regex = "(<?I am going)(.+)(?>manchester)";
  final String string = "I am going with my family to manchester patata";

  final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
  final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
  String answer = "";

  while (matcher.find()) {
   answer = matcher.group(0) + "";
  }


  System.out.println(answer);
 }
}
```